# Prevent Action being set to null (except privately)

Tags: c#, null, action, private

I'm trying to write code in a way that limits the surface area for error, by exposing only what I want the `public` users to be able to play with.

In this case, I have an `Action` that I want `public` users to be able to subscribe or unsubscribe to. However, I don't want those users to be able to adversely affect OTHER users, i.e. by unsubscribing EVERYBODY.

```
public class X
{
    public static Action a;
}

public class Mistake
{
    public void Oops()
    {
        X.a = null;
        // I just cleared ALL subscribers to X.a - not just my own subscription.
    }
}
```

One way around this is to hide the `Action` itself, and instead present methods to sub/unsub to it:

```
public class X
{
    static Action _a;

    public static void SubA(Action cb) =>
        _a += cb;
    public static void UnsubA(Action cb) =>
        _a -= cb;
}
```

This works - it's already a lot harder to make a similar kind of mistake. However, it's a little more verbose than I'd like.

Hence my question:

**Is there any "nice"/idiomatic way to allow public `X.a += ...` and `X.a -= ...`, but disallow public `X.a = null;`?**

I tried using an auto-property `public static Action A { get; private set;  }`, but as expected, that prevented usage of `+=` and `-=` publicly.

I suspect that there may be a way to put a wrapping property around `X.a` whose setter throws/does nothing when `value == null`, but even if that worked, I feel that it's still unpleasantly verbose.

If this isn't possible with `Action`, but something approximately similar is possible with event/delegate (which I know very little about), I'd also be interested!

Hope you're all enjoying the festive season

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **might** work for you, depending exactly what you need

```
private Action _myActon;

public event Action MyAction
{
   add => _myActon += value;
   remove => _myActon -= value;
} 

...

MyAction += () => Console.WriteLine("test1");
MyAction += () => Console.WriteLine("test2");
MyAction += null;
//MyAction = null // compiler error;

...

_myActon.Invoke();
_myActon= null;
```

**Output**

```
test1
test2
```

To the compiler Events and Delegate have a lot in common, using event keywords and the above pattern limits the ability to assign null, there is also some subtle other differences, however I'll try and find some reputable sources.

---

**Additional Resources**

A detailed description of events and delegates, lots of fun for the whole family here

- [Delegates and Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ff652490(v=orm.10))

  - > **The event Keyword**
    >
    > The event keyword indicates to the compiler that the delegate can be
    >   invoked only by the defining class, and that other classes can
    >   subscribe to and unsubscribe from the delegate using only the
    >   appropriate += and -= operators, respectively.
- [How to: Implement Custom Event Accessors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-implement-custom-event-accessors)

  - > An event is a special kind of multicast delegate that can only be
    >   invoked from within the class that it is declared in. Client code
    >   subscribes to the event by providing a reference to a method that
    >   should be invoked when the event is fired. These methods are added to
    >   the delegate's invocation list through event accessors, which resemble
    >   property accessors, except that event accessors are named add and
    >   remove.
- [add (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/add)

  - > The add contextual keyword is used to define a custom event accessor
    >   that is invoked when client code subscribes to your event. If you
    >   supply a custom add accessor, you must also supply a remove accessor.
- [Delegates and Events (C# in Depth) Jon Skeet](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx)

Comment: Wow! I'm not familiar with this construct at all, but it seems great. Is there a name for this technique that I can read into? Thanks @TheGeneral, I honestly wasn't expecting a solution when I asked the question, but am now glad I did 

Comment: I didn't know that events, by definition, only allowed the defining class to set to null. Considering that, a straightforward `public event Action MyAction;` works without the custom event accessors, allowing me to remove the private field entirely. Can't get more "nice" than that!

Comment: @BilalAkil this is correct, i made a comment of that, and removed it, however i left the verbose accessor in so you could see how you can add more power (depending on your needs) and leave the Action as a vanilla Action

Comment: It looks like the variable `_myAciton` is consistently misspelled throughout. Would this be clearer spelled correctly, or is there a purpose to the transposition?